# Low volume in mp3 using media element

Tags: silverlight, media, element

I am playing a mp3 using Windows Media plaver, its fine, but same file playing in Silverlight 3.0 using Media Element, its volume is low, so what should I do to increase the volume,.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MediaElement.Volume

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.volume%28v=VS.90%29.aspx

> The media's volume represented on a linear scale between 0 and 1. The default is 0.5.

You can also boost the volume in the source media. If you're using Expression Encoder look under Enhance Tab > Pre-Processing > Audio

Comment: We already set Volume to 1. we are not using Expression Encoder now.

Comment: @Imenaria Then your only option is to boost the volume of the source in whatever tool you're using.

Comment: Problem is very old and it still is not solved. Just listen to one and the same record in different players. All of them sound louder than WPF MediaElement set to Volume==1.